# Providing a buffer to receive an Out LPWSTR value

Tags: delphi

I rarely use the Windows API directly, but I have a situation where it is unavoidable and I'm not sure how to deal with it.

The MS API documentation refers to a parameter to an API call like

```
out Something LPWSTR
```

so I evidently have to provide a buffer to receive it, but how am I supposed to know what size of buffer to provide?  I suppose I could try calling StrLen on Something but that seems to mean that I would need to call the API twice, once to get the length and a second time to actually retrieve the result, and the length may have changed in the meantime.

OTOH, I could pre-allocate the buffer (e.g. as a local WideChar array), but that seems a bit impractical because the string returned could be of any arbitrary length(?).

So, my q is how to correctly receive the value of an Out LPWSTR? ANd, as a supplementary, how do I find its encoding (or does the Win API always use the same encoding and if so which?)

I'm asking about post-Unicode versions of Delphi.

Comment: You really need to say what API call you are looking at.

Comment: @TomBrunberg:  Thanks, but how come?  If the API doc doesn't specify a maximum possible length, doesn't that give the API carte blanche to return whatever length.  As it happens, I'm asking about filesystem APIs where I suppose the max length would be MAXPATH, but I'm asking in general, not specific to that.

Comment: Will you or will you not tell me which API function you want to call? There might be different schemes, I do not want to speculate.

Comment: I guess you have [some reading to do](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN), anyway using the NT style names ("\\?\") you have a hard limit of 32,767 unicode characters, so preallocate around that number...

Comment: The answer is that, well, it depends. Show the detail and we will happily answer.

Comment: I wonder why downvoted?  The OP is obviously talking about an API that has no input param to specify the maximum number of chars to return.  An example that springs to mind from smth I was looking into recently is IShellItem.GetDisplayName, where there is no way to explicitly specify a maximum ret length.

Comment: @MartynA I did not dv, but I asked twice for an example function, specifically to clarify what OP is talking about.  The only clue OP responded with was `filesystem API` and `MAXPATH`. Seeing that I am now rewarded with a dv, makes *me* wonder why.

Comment: Sorry, @TomBrunberg, but I was asking because think it is a reasonable question to ask in general terms, because there are APIs where there is no obvious input param.  It's a point that's occurred to me more than once, and I've honestly never known whether there is a single, Windows-wide answer. Apparently not, judging by other comments ...

Comment: @MartynA For `IShellItem::GetDisplayName` the string is allocated by the callee using the COM allocator, and the caller frees it using `CoTaskMemFree`. It's clearly documented as such. This is the other common model and why there is no single answer to the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Thanks, this is reminding me why I steer well clear of this kind of stuff unless its absolutely unavoidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to answer this definitively since you did not mention the exact API function you want to call. But in general, there are two models used for memory management in the Win32 API:

- the caller allocates a buffer of sufficient size, and then the API fills the buffer with data.
- the API allocates and fills a buffer with data, and then returns it to the caller, who must then free it.

Tom's answer provides an example of the first case, so I'll provide an example of the second case.

In Delphi, `out ParamName: LPWSTR` means the parameter is an output-only reference to a pointer type. That would be `LPWSTR*` (`wchar_t**`) in C and `LPWSTR&` (`wchar_t*&`) in C++. And since it is a reference to a pointer type, the function likely allocates the necessary memory and returns it to the caller via the reference, and then the caller is expected to free it afterwards.

Since you mentioned filesystem APIs, let's look at the [`IShellItem.GetDisplayName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellitem-getdisplayname) API as an example, which has such a parameter:

> ```c
> HRESULT GetDisplayName(
>   SIGDN sigdnName,
>   LPWSTR *ppszName
> );
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> `sigdnName`
>   Type: SIGDN
>   One of the SIGDN values that indicates how the name should look.
>
> `ppszName`
>   Type: LPWSTR*
>   A value that, when this function returns successfully, **receives the address of a pointer to the retrieved display name.**
>
> ...
>
> Remarks
>
> **It is the responsibility of the caller to free the string pointed to by `ppszName` when it is no longer needed. Call CoTaskMemFree on `*ppszName` to free the memory.**

So, in Delphi, that `GetDisplayName()` method could be declared and used in one of two different ways:

```pascal
type
  IShellitem = interface
    ['{43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe}']
    ...
    function GetDisplayName(sigdnName: SIGDN, out ppszName: LPWSTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    ...
  end;

...

var
  Item: IShellItem;
  Path: PWideChar;
begin
  // obtain Item as needed, then...
  OleCheck(Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH, Path));
  try
    // use Path as needed...
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(Path);
  end;
end;
```

```pascal
type
  IShellitem = interface
    ['{43826d1e-e718-42ee-bc55-a1e261c37bfe}']
    ...
    function GetDisplayName(sigdnName: SIGDN): LPWSTR; safecall;
    ...
  end;

...

var
  Item: IShellItem;
  Path: PWideChar;
begin
  // obtain Item as needed, then...
  Path := Item.GetDisplayName(SIGDN_FILESYSPATH);
  try
    // use Path as needed...
  finally
    CoTaskMemFree(Path);
  end;
end;
```

[`SHGetKnownFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shgetknownfolderpath) is another example of a filesystem API with a similar output parameter:

> ```c
> HRESULT SHGetKnownFolderPath(
>   REFKNOWNFOLDERID rfid,
>   DWORD dwFlags,
>   HANDLE hToken,
>   PWSTR *ppszPath
> );
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `ppszPath`
>   Type: PWSTR*
>   When this method returns, **contains the address of a pointer to a null-terminated Unicode string that specifies the path of the known folder. The calling process is responsible for freeing this resource once it is no longer needed by calling CoTaskMemFree.** The returned path does not include a trailing backslash. For example, "C:\Users" is returned rather than "C:\Users\".

Comment: Brilliant explanation, +1.  Obviously I need to make a point of looking at the Remarks in the MS OLH.

Answer (score 6):

While waiting for your response to comments: consider, f.i, `GetTempPathW()` function. It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-gettemppathw) as follows

```
DWORD GetTempPathW(
  DWORD  nBufferLength,
  LPWSTR lpBuffer
);
```

> **nBufferLength**
>
> The size of the string buffer identified by lpBuffer, in TCHARs.
>
> **lpBuffer**
>
> A pointer to a string buffer that receives the null-terminated string
>   specifying the temporary file path.
>
> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in TCHARs,
>   of the string copied to lpBuffer, not including the terminating null
>   character. If the return value is greater than nBufferLength, the
>   return value is the length, in TCHARs, of the buffer required to hold
>   the path.

So yes, if you want to allocate a buffer of the correct length you need to call it first with `nBufferLength = 0`, or small enough. Then use the return value to allocate the buffer and call the function again.